# Highcharts-ng dynamic config binding

Tags: angularjs, highcharts-ng

I am having trouble having highcharts bind to a dynamic chartConfig using this approach

where charts is an object in the controller housing multiple charts by the keys "{{moment}}_a".

When the page resolves, the highcharts has the right output, for e.g.

config="charts['ABC-DEF_a']" but the chart and data don't display. If I manually type the same config="charts['ABC-DEF_a']" into the page, it displays fine.

How do I ensure that highcharts binds to the variable referenced?

Thanks

Comment: It might have something to do with the directive not watching (correctly) when the config parameter is changed. If you look at the code https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/blob/master/src/highcharts-ng.js perhaps you can figure something out? :-|

Answer (score 0):

If you use for example `config="chartConfig"` you edit it via controller by `$scope.chartConfig = {};` and after any dynamic change you must call `$scope.$apply();`